# Unused variable when using jQuery UI API

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

When using the jQuery UI API, I run into the "Unused variable" problem when running my plugin through jsLint.

Example:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $.cookie( opts.cookieName + "_" + that.index(), ui.index );
}
```

In this case, I only need the ui.index, but event is unused. But the API requires me to pass both parameters.

Is there a work around to this or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal.  It is often the case the event object is not used when responding to UI events

Comment: I figured that was the case, but wanted to make sure. Thanks Hogan.